# How to fix CORS issue in Hostgator Shared Hosting

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, cors, cpanel

I am using 3rd party API from which I am getting the below error:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myapi/..' from origin 'https://mydomain.xyz' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I am wondering how to enable CORS policy in my application. my .htaccess file is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" // this line I added but no work
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am using Laravel application. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also use [Cors package for laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62356247/how-to-fix-cors-issue-in-hostgator-shared-hosting). It goes by default in laravel 7

Answer (score 0):

Did you
Add/activate module?

`a2enmod headers` 
And after 
restart service

`/etc/init.t/apache2 restart`

Also you can use https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors